# Stuck in 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error in our nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cors, http-headers

Our nodeJS app is deployed at **AWS-lambda** and we are trying to request authentication and were getting this error in the console

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://vklut41ib9.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/auth/login'
> from origin 'https://our-app.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource.

But the weird thing is we're not getting this error when we're attempting with the wrong credentials

[image: Response & Headers during false credentials]

Just when we are attempting to access with true credentials we're getting cors error

[image]

Our app.js code:

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const serverless = require("serverless-http");
// const http = require("http");

// var server = http.createServer(app);

dotenv.config({ path: "./src/config/config.env" });

// files
const connectDb = require("./src/config/db");
const auth = require("./src/routes/apis/auth");
const user = require("./src/routes/apis/user");


// database connection
connectDb();

app.use(cors());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// passport config
require("./src/config/passport")(passport);

// passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "key",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);

app.use("/api/auth", auth);
app.use("/api/users", user);



module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

Our auth route:

```
// auth route for login user
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { workerId, workerPassword } = req.body;

  try {
    const foundUser = await User.findOne({ workerId });
    if (!foundUser) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: "Employee does not exist (Invalid Employee ID)",
      });
    } else if (foundUser.totalLoginAttemptLeft > 0) {
      const checkPasswordData = await checkPassword(workerPassword, foundUser);
      if (!checkPasswordData.isMatch) {
        await passwordNotMatched(res, checkPasswordData.updatedWorker);
      } else {
        const jwtToken = await totalLogin(foundUser, reset);
        return res.status(200).json({ token: "Bearer " + jwtToken });
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

Token generation code:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

// make jwt token
const makeToken = async (payload) => {
  const jwtToken = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
    expiresIn: "7d",
  });
  if (!jwtToken) {
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  }
  return jwtToken;
};

module.exports = makeToken;
```

Client-side login handling

```
const loginUser = (loginInfo, loginType) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { baseUrlNode } = await helperFunction.checkLoginType(
      loginType
    );

   
    const loginSuccess = await axios.post(
      `${baseUrlNode}${api.Auth_Api.LOGIN_API}`,
      loginInfo
    );
    // console.log(loginSuccess);
    const { token = "" } = loginSuccess.data;
    const { id, workerId, workerAadharCardNumber } = jwt_decode(
      token
    );

    if (id && workerId && workerAadharCardNumber && loginType) {
      await setLocalStorage(token, loginType);
      setAuthToken(token);
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    } else {
      dispatch(setAuthLoading(false));
      const errorData = {
        data: { message: "Not able to login" },
        status: 400
      };

      dispatch({
        type: types.AuthTypes.AUTH_GET_ERRORS,
        payload: errorData
      });
    }
  } catch (loginError) {
    const errorData = {
      data: loginError.response.data,
      status: loginError.response.status
    };

    dispatch({
      type: types.AuthTypes.AUTH_GET_ERRORS,
      payload: errorData
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you see the response header ... `x-amzn-errortype` - that probably explains the issue - there's some "InternalServerErrorException"

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes x-amzn-errortype is present

Answer (score -1):

The No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present error can occur for any of the following reasons:

- **method type (such as GET, PUT, or POST) isn't configured to return the required CORS headers.**
- **The API isn't configured with an OPTIONS method that returns the required CORS headers**
- **An API with proxy integration or non-proxy integration isn't configured to return the required CORS headers.**

So I suggest adding this code or just update yours with the part that allows the method types (GET, POST, PUT, etc.)

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, 'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data' ,* "
  );
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});
```

Also, I recommend reading this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/no-access-control-allow-origin-error/)

and this one as well [article2](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cors-errors/)